# Laravel5 Unit Testing a Login Form

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-dusk

I ran the following test and I am receiving a failed_asserting that false is true. Can someone further explain why this could be?

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_logs_in()
{
    $user =  factory(App\User::class)->create(['email' => 'john@example.com', 'password' => bcrypt('testpass123')]);

    $this->visit(route('login'));
    $this->type($user->email, 'email');
    $this->type($user->password, 'password');
    $this->press('Login');
    $this->assertTrue(Auth::check());
    $this->seePageIs(route('dashboard'));
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use Auth facade in this context. User is logged in on other side of the application, not on your 'testing' side so to say. Therefore, developers usually ensure the login worked using something $this->see('Log out') because 'Log out' button only appears once you are logged in, for instance.

Comment: So your saying that the method that is ran after the login page is submitted should direct them to dashboard if its a successful login?

Comment: yes, in your test you should look whether you got inside the dashboard, you don't check Auth facade - it won't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PHPUnit test is a client, not the web application itself. Therefore Auth::check() shouldn't return true. Instead, you could check that you are on the right page after pressing the button and that you see some kind of confirmation text:

```
    /** @test */
    public function a_user_can_log_in()
    {
        $user = factory(App\User::class)->create([
             'email' => 'john@example.com', 
             'password' => bcrypt('testpass123')
        ]);

        $this->visit(route('login'))
            ->type($user->email, 'email')
            ->type('testpass123', 'password')
            ->press('Login')
            ->see('Successfully logged in')
            ->onPage('/dashboard');
    }
```

I believe this is how most developers would do it. Even if Auth::check() worked – it would only mean a session variable is created, you would still have to test that you are properly redirected to the right page, etc.

Comment: What if the user is already logged in when they hit the login page?

Comment: You can add another test for that :) eg. logged_in_user_cannot_login_again() :)

Comment: would that be filling in the form with the hashed version of the password ?

Comment: @lagbox it's not hashed but it's not correct either – 'password' should be 'testpass123' of course. I edited the original code and I missed this ;)

Comment: it is hashed, if it wasn't auth wouldn't be able to match the password .. also those `type` calls are not correct

Comment: @lagbox my bad, you are right! :) I was in a rush, fixed the typo now. thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I am doing this exactly and I am getting a failed login

Answer (score 2):

In your test you can use your Model to get the user, and you can use ->be($user) so that it will get Authenticate.

So i written in my test case for API test

```
    $user = new User(['name' => 'peak']);
    $this->be($user)
         ->get('/api/v1/getManufacturer')
          ->seeJson([
             'status' => true,
         ]);
```

it works for me

Comment: hope it is useful,Thank you!